# Run a command each time a file is saved

Tags: front-end, notebooks, files-and-directories, save

Is there any way to get Mathematica to run a function each time I save a file? So either by ctrl-s or by the 'save' command in the file menu.

Then I could, for example, ask it to make a copy of the saved file in a different location each time I save it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`NotebookEventActions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEventActions) for this:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions] = {
    {"MenuCommand","Save"}:>Print[1],
    PassEventsDown->True
}
```

Replace `Print[1]` with your function.

Comment: Worth mentioning `EvaluationOrder` here, too. If they want the action to occur *after* the save (as is often the case) they'll need that.